# Do auxiliary verbs have a meaning / an intrinsic meaning?

Tags: meaning, semantics, auxiliary-verbs

1. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_auxiliary_verbs):

> English auxiliary verbs are a small set of English verbs, which
> include the English modal auxiliary verbs and a few others. Although
> the auxiliary verbs of English are widely believed to lack inherent
> semantic meaning and instead to modify the meaning of the verbs they
> accompany ...

2. "The Grammar of the English Tense System" by Susan Reed and Bert Capelle:

> Unlike a lexical verb, an auxiliary has little or no lexical meaning:
> it expresses either a grammatical notion (like passive, progressive,
> tense) or a modal idea (like necessity, possibility) or it has no
> meaning at all and is used simply because an auxiliary is required in
> certain contexts.

3. "Writing English" by Dr. George Stern

> Auxiliary verb: any of a small subset of verbs used in such a way that
> the verb has no meaning, but rather, helps to perform a grammar
> function. Auxiliary verbs contrast with lexical verbs, which do have
> meaning. ... In addition to the three primary auxiliary verbs
> discussed above, many grammarians also include the modal verbs in this
> category.

4. "Exploring Grammar Through Texts" by Cornelia Paraskevas

> Contrary to the primary auxiliary (i.e. be, have, do), which do not
> have meaning of their own, these modals verbs contribute notios such
> as possibility, probability ... to the meaning of the verb that
> follows them. ... the modals verbs contribute additional meanings to
> the main verb, which primary auxiliaries do not.

5. "A Student's Introduction to English Grammar" by Huddleston and Pullum:

> ... we add the auxiliary verb do. This has no meaning of its own ...

The above quotations from different grammar books provide contradictory information. Wikipedia and Dr. Stern state that auxiliary verbs (including modal auxiliary verbs) do not have an intrinsic meaning. Susan Reed and Bert Capelle state that auxiliary verbs have little or no lexical meaning. Cornelia Paraskevas states that the primary auxiliary verbs do not have meaning, but the modal auxiliary verbs do have meaning.

**Question 1: Do the auxiliary verbs "be", "have" and "do" have a meaning?**

**Question 2: Do the modal auxiliary verbs have a meaning?**

Comment: What do you mean by "have a meaning"?

Comment: Does it not depend on context? `Do something!` or `I am.` The verbs have their own meaning, only if used as auxiliary they have no meaning of their own...?

Comment: Aren't  you missing proformation in your list? A: *Nobody we know studies French*; B: "Anne **does**." Here *does* takes on a very specific (non-inherent) meaning that isn't modification or modal-related.

Comment: @Lukas In "Do something," *do* is not an auxiliary. Note that, if we turn this into a question, we get e.g. "Did you do something?", *adding* an auxiliary *do,* rather than \*"Did you something?"

Comment: Some of these verbs happen to have separate, "inherent" meanings. "A piece of tape will **do** (suffice)." "The little girl thought you could **will** a pony into existence." Of course they are not models in that role.

Comment: @DjinnTonic Arguably 'be', 'have' and 'do' used as non-auxiliaries are different words; some even class auxiliaries separately from verbs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wouldn't disagree. They are certainly distinct from auxiliaries. However, their "other" meanings are usually related when you think about it.

Comment: You do not fully quote that first paragraph, which states that the meaning of auxiliaries is not found via semantics but via grammar. Basically, they are all saying that **in the context of semantics** an auxiliary is not meaningful. They **are however meaningful in grammar**.  The do in Do you speak English? does not have lexical meaning. Its meaning comes from the question form: Do [subject] verb? . However, that does not mean that "do" in "I do the work every day" does not have lexical meaning because it certainly does. Learning to read carefully is important.

Comment: Our mind jumps when we see an auxiliary has no meaning, and we tend to brush away the word lexical as in lexical meaning, when in fact that is exactly what they're saying (they are all saying the same basic thing). So, restated: **auxiliaries draw meaning from their grammatical context and not from semantics (lexical meaning**).

Comment: 1 - If all books agreed precisely, we'd need only one book. 2 - They are saying that 5% is like zero or trivial, not disagreeing that auxiliaries are helpers in context. Say they have presentation value, not a main dish.

Comment: No word has an intrinsic meaning. Meaning is only given by words' use in human interactions.

Comment: The auxiliary (dummy) verb "do" is used in negation and certain interrogatives. Unlike some other auxiliaries, it has no meaning of its own.

Comment: Although all modals stemmed from full verbs, few are now also full verbs with that earlier meaning. Modals now act to inform you of the mode of their verb; they are a catalyst. Consider -- **Don’t touch that, it burns you** -- **Don’t touch that, it could burn you** -> *Don’t touch that, it possesses the potential to burn you/of burning you.* -- **Don’t touch that, it can burn you.** -> *Don’t touch that, it possesses the ability to burn you/of burning you.* -- The questions are “Does ‘could’ mean ‘possesses the potential’ and is “to burn” a substantive as “burning” is?”

Comment: @BillJ I understand that „do“ has no meaning of its own. What about „be“, „have“ and the modal auxiliaries? I would say that they do not have meaning of their own too, because they add to or change the meaning of the lexical / main verb.

Comment: @alphabet That is exactly what I meant. Whether the mentioned words are auxiliary depends on how they are used. And if not auxiliary they have meaning. Nice example with the "Did you do"

Comment: @R.J. The modals do have an independent meaning (epistemic, deontic, dymamic). The auxiliaries "be" and "have" do not.

Comment: @BillJ If you formulate your comment in a more elaborate answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

In 'have/take a bath', 'have' and 'take' are considered to be semantically bleached, having no or negligible meaning on their own. They are functional as opposed to lexical words:

- I'm about to ..... a bath

obviously requires some verb in the slot, but '[V] a bath' is merely a variant on the rare 'bathe': 'have' contributes only grammaticality. Contrast 'buy' in

- I'm about to buy a bath.

Hence, they are called *light verbs* or *delexical verbs* [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_verb)] when used this way (contrast 'He decided to take her some roses' where 'take' is lexical, meaning 'procure and deliver in person to').

Auxiliaries are certainly carriers (a trivial name is 'helper verb'): they are used to facilitate constructions. Those without modal significance (be, have, do, and the periphrastic used to) usually have little semantic weight (though note that emphatic do ('I *do* have to get this done by tonight') certainly adds a layer of meaning.

But modals certainly affect the meaning of a sentence.

'I must do this' is certainly not synonymous with 'I will do this' (or 'I can do this' ...), though all of course are grammatical and idiomatic. But what the modals actually add to a statement / question etc is best explained not in the usual dictionary way of giving one or more reasonable tight-as-possible synonyms for lexical words, but in the way say ODE does:

> **may** [verb]
>
> - 1. expressing possibility.
>
> "*that may be true*"
>
> - 2. used to ask for or to give permission.
>
> "*you may confirm my identity with your Case Officer, if you wish*"

[[ODE; courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=may+meaning&sca_esv=d15b179212b804a0&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=nRbWZZegF9ybhbIPiOqFkAw&ved=0ahUKEwjX4svU37yEAxXcTUEAHQh1AcIQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=may+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiC21heSBtZWFuaW5nMhMQABiABBiKBRiRAhixAxhGGPkBMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIKEAAYgAQYigUYQzIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yBhAAGAcYHjIKEAAYgAQYigUYQzIGEAAYBxgeMgYQABgHGB4yLRAAGIAEGIoFGJECGLEDGEYY-QEYlwUYjAUY3QQYRhj5ARj0Axj1Axj2A9gBAUj8IVDKFVjQGXABeACQAQCYAWqgAbcCqgEDMy4xuAEDyAEA-AEBwgIKEAAYRxjWBBiwA8ICDRAAGIAEGIoFGEMYsAPCAg4QABiABBiKBRiRAhixA8ICLRAAGIAEGIoFGJECGLEDGEYY-QEYlwUYjAUY3QQYRhj5ARj0Axj1Axj2A9gBAYgGAZAGCroGBggBEAEYEw&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

So modals certainly affect the meaning of a sentence, but in a way subtly different from usual lexical words. And though they also overlap function words, being used to form constructions, and not really outside them, I certainly wouldn't apply the terms 'bleached of meaning' or 'delexical' to them. In fact, in 'You really ought to V', the thrust of the sentence is the responsibility [the deontic reading] or urgency [the hortative reading] conveyed by the modal 'ought [to]'.

Comment: ODE? There is of course no hortative mood in English grammar --- and no optative
mood, and no subjunctive mood either. Wikipedia is just silly about this, as many grammars are. Functional words? All words are either lexical or auxiliary. Are you quoting from The Comprehensive or some other out-of-date grammar?